# Stream data into hdfs directly without copying

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I am looking for different options through which I can write data directly into hdfs using python without storing on the local node and then using copyfromlocal.

I would like to use hdfs file similar to local file and use write method with the line as the argument, something of the following:

```
   hdfs_file = hdfs.create("file_tmp")
   hdfs_file.write("Hello world\n")
```

Does there exist something similar to the use case described above?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Im not sure about a python hdfs library, but you can always stream via a hadoop fs put command and denote copying from stdin using '-' as the source filename:

```
hadoop fs -put - /path/to/file/in/hdfs.txt
```

Comment: This is cool. Can I use redirection operator here? I can write to console through python and redirect the output to the above command.

Comment: Thanks, I piped the output from python to the above command and it worked.