# Save JSON to HDFS using python

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I have a python script which currently accesses an API which returns JSON. It then takes the JSON string and saves it off as a file on the local file system, where i then move it into HDFS manually. I would like to change this so my python script is saving directly to HDFS instead of hitting the local file system first. I am currently trying to save the file using HDFS and DFS command but I don't think the copy command is the correct way to do this because it isn't a file but rather a JSON string when I am trying to save it.

Current Code

```
import urllib2
import json
import os

f = urllib2.urlopen('RESTful_API_URL.json')
json_string = json.loads(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
with open('\home\user\filename.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_string,outfile)
```

New Code

```
f = urllib2.urlopen('RESTful_API_URL.json')
json_string = json.loads(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
os.environ['json_string'] = json.dump(json_string)
os.system('hdfs dfs -cp -f $json_string hdfs/user/test')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is the same with this thread [Stream data into hdfs directly without copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454244/stream-data-into-hdfs-directly-without-copying).

Firstly, this command can redirect stdin to hdfs file,

```
hadoop fs -put - /path/to/file/in/hdfs.txt
```

Then, you can do this in python,

```
os.system('echo "%s" | hadoop fs -put - /path/to/file/in/hdfs.txt' %(json.dump(json_string)))
```

Comment: the file is created but no contents have written in to the file in HDFS... what would be the issue?

Comment: If you use echo "%s" , your json file will be stored without double quotes

Comment: I used the same technique, the JSON string is not copied in HDFS? any reason.

Comment: @eval , when i use the os.system('echo "%s" | hadoop fs -put - /path/to/file/in/hdfs.txt' %(json.dump(json_string))) iam getting prefix u and ' ' char before.     {u'manager':u'robert',u'name':u'kim'}  ,how i can remove u and ' ' for every key ,value in my json

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the HDFS put command at http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put

You can put to HDFS from the command line using standard in with syntax like the following (`-put -` means read from stdin).

```
hadoop fs -put - hdfs://nn.example.com/hadoop/hadoopfile
```

If you can start this command as a sub process within your python code, you should be able to pipe your json string to the sub process.

Answer (score -1):

It helped in my case:

```
import os
import requests

r = requests.get(url = url,headers=headers)
json_string = r.json()
os.system('echo "%s" | hadoop fs -put - /<your_hdfs_path>/json_name.json' %(json_string))
```