# Using python to push data into HDFS

Tags: python, hadoop

I'm using the following python code, run through PuTTy, to call an API for some weather forecast data:

```
r = requests.get('http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/xml/350509?res=3hourly&key=abc-123-mnb-0987')
```

Please can anyone advise on the correct syntax to pipe this data straight through into HDFS (i'm running the HDF 2.4 sandbox on a VM)?

Comment: Possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099664/save-json-to-hdfs-using-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
r = requests.get('http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/xml/350509?res=3hourly&key=abc-123-mnb-0987') 
os.system('echo "%s" | hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal - /path/in/hdfs' %(r.text))
```